# jQuery each callback

Tags: jquery, callback, each

How to use callbacks on [jQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function?

I am trying something like:

```
$.each(images, function(key, value) { 
    new_images+= '<li><a href="'+value+'"><img src="'+value+'" alt="'+[key]+'" /></a></li>';
}, function (){
    $('#Gallery').remove();
    $('body').append('<ul class="gallery">'+new_images+'</ul>');
});
```

Comment: why callback? If you want to perform an action after an .each which is synchronous(!) you just write your code after the .each()

Comment: Why are you using two functions? The `each` function doesn't support that. Instead, include the 2nd function's statements within the first one.

Comment: `.each` only takes two values (a collection and a function), but you've passed it three (collection(?), function, function). What are you trying to do?

Comment: @devnull69 the array is big (about 300 images) and so it can take a while... Is it good to use without callback?

Comment: @Jim just trying to get callback on it.

Comment: @NoNameZ Where is the problem with growing a string in 300 steps? There is no DOM method involved ...

Comment: @devnull69 What if DOM method involved? how to solve it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What's wrong with this code? You don't need a callback for `$.each`.

```
$.each(images, function(key, value) { 
    new_images+= '<li><a href="'+value+'"><img src="'+value+'" alt="'+[key]+'" /></a></li>';
});

$('#Gallery').remove();
$('body').append('<ul class="gallery">'+new_images+'</ul>');
```

Answer (score 49):

`$.each();` is a synchronous function. That means you don't need a callback function inside because any code you write after `$.each();` will run affter `$.each();` ends.

Comment: the confusion arises because people (mis)use the term "callback" to refer to any time a function reference is passed, whether that function is subsequently called asynchronously, or not.

Comment: @Alnitak I intuitively see a callback as some kind of trigger to execute code after a certain block/function/process/animation is finished. If this isn't correct or even just incomplete interpretation, could you refer me to some documentation that might help me grasp the concept better? The comment you made completely through me off, mainly because I'm still trying to learn all this "lingo"

Comment: @FernandoSilva well, see for example the MDN documentation for `Array.prototype.map` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map - They call the supplied function `callback` even though it isn't "something called after".

Comment: @Alnitak so basically what you're saying is a callback is simply a reference to a function that will be executed within the function that passes that reference? `Array.prototype.map` cycles through an array and given certain conditions executes the passed `callback` function. So what we usually see in jQuery as a `callback` is simply a way to reference a function, that usually gets triggered after the success or complete is achieved, like with an animation and that's how people usually associate the `callback` term to an event type of thing? Is this correct?

Comment: @Alnitak now you got me thinking. If I wanted to implement the callback behaviour, in php I would do something like `function foo($callback){//do something; $callback();}`, how could I achieve the same in javascript, would it be the same? `function jsFoo(callback){//do something; callback();}` ?

Comment: Are you sure? Actually I am still in confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
$.each(images, function(key, value) { 
    new_images+= '<li><a href="'+value+'"><img src="'+value+'" alt="'+[key]+'" /></a></li>';
});
function myMethod(){
    $('#Gallery').remove();
    $('body').append('<ul class="gallery">'+new_images+'</ul>');
};
myMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have now a solution for an .each-callback!

I had to do an ajax-request for each element in an array. So I made a div-container with all the div-elements for each element. Each time a load was made, the div-element changed to green and .slideUp, after .remove.
And each time i asked if the div-container is empty. If yes, I know, all elements are fully loades (because removed).

Here a part of my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.each(myChannels, function(index, value) {
        $("#tag_"+value).load('getxmls/ajaxrenewchannel/channel:'+value, function() {
            $("#tag_"+value).removeClass('alert-info').addClass('alert-success');
            $("#tag_"+value).slideUp('600', function () {
                $("#tag_"+value).remove();
                if( $('#loadcontainer').is(':empty') ) {
                    window.location = 'feeds/';
                }

                });

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps somebody out there...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the callback you meant. I guess this is what you are looking for

```
$('#Gallery').remove();
var selectItems='<ul class="gallery">';
$.each(images, function(key, value) { 
    selectItems+= '<li><a href="'+value+'">
                              <img src="'+value+'" alt="'+[key]+'" /></a></li>';    
});   
selectItems+= '</ul>';
$('body').append(selectItems);
```